# Platform/version-independent sorting for gnu sort

Tags: cygwin, sorting, synology, gnu

I am trying to do an offline comparison of two lists generated on two different systems. They both have GNU coreutils so to aid the diff'ing, I sort both lists using `sort` before transferring them.

I've noticed that the two implementations have different sorting criteria. The value of LANG did initially differ, but reconciling them doesn't seem to change anything.

For example, the following command produces different output:

```
LANG=C echo -e "a\n.a"|sort
```

On one, I get:

```
.a
a
```

On the other I get

```
a
.a
```

I haven't dove into the coreutils code, but I suspect this is due to OS-dependent sorting APIs, but is there a way to force GNU sort to sort consistently across platforms?

Note that I realize that I could just transfer the file to one of the two and sort there, which is likely what I'll do in the short term, but I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid this.

In this case, the two systems are Cygwin64 and whatever Synology concocted. They both identify as GNU `sort` (8.26 and 8.30, respectively):

Cygwin:

```
$ sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.26
Packaged by Cygwin (8.26-2)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and Paul Eggert.
```

Synology:

```
$ sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.30
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and Paul Eggert.
```

Comment: check the value of LANG

Comment: Good point. Forgot that. Turns out they were different. Unfortunately, changing it didn't change anything :(

Comment: the dot is before any number or letter in the ASCII table and in UTF8 so to me it seems the Synology system is doing something wrong. What is the output of `LANG=C echo -e "a\n.a" | od -t x1` ?

Comment: They both output the same ASCII (`61 0a 2e 61 0a`)